# Rails + Capybara: 'Unexpected Alert Open' for Selenium Driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, capybara

I am using Capybara and Chrome as my default selenium browser.

Test:

```
it "is successful with deleting a user", js: true do
  visit '/users'
  expect(User.count).to eq(1)
  expect(user.email).to eq("ryan@drake.com")
  expect(page).to have_content("Manage Users")
  click_link 'Delete User'
  page.driver.browser.confirm.accept
  user.reload
  visit '/users'
  expect(User.count).to eq(0)
end
```

I'm getting this error for my test:

```
Failure/Error: visit '/users'
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError:
   unexpected alert open
```

I have tried the following in my test:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.confirm
page.driver.browser.switch_to.accept
page.driver.browser.confirm.accept
```

Any other variations I should try with my test?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try wrapping the code that will initiate the alert prompt inside of an `accept_alert` block, like this:

```
it "is successful with deleting a user", js: true do
  visit '/users'
  expect(User.count).to eq(1)
  expect(user.email).to eq("ryan@drake.com")
  expect(page).to have_content("Manage Users")

  # Change is here:
  accept_alert do
    click_link 'Delete User'
  end

  user.reload
  visit '/users'
  expect(User.count).to eq(0)
end
```

I'm a little concerned that you would want to use an alert rather than a confirmation when deleting a resource, but that's up to you. An alert is just going to tell you that something is going to happen, meanwhile a confirmation allows the user to change their mind by hitting cancel instead of OK. If you use a confirmation modal instead of an alert modal then the `accept_alert`part would need to be changed to `accept_confirm`.

Check out [the modal documentation rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara#Modals) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I just got the same error.

Checking the capybara documentation at [rubydoc.info](https://www.rubydoc.info), I found that the following methods solve the issue:

[accept_confirm](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#accept_confirm-instance_method): "Execute the block, accepting a confirm."

[dismiss_confirm](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#dismiss_confirm-instance_method): "Execute the block, dismissing a confirm."